# Attach Database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm new in database programming  ,I can not attach SQL Server 2008 .Could not load file or assembly `file :\\C:Windows\system32\SqlManagerUi.dll'` or one of its dependecies.System cannot the file (mscorlib) Could you help me please?

---

Sorry,

Correct path is :'file///C:\Windows\System32\SqlManagerUi.dll' or one of its dependicies.

Could you help me please?

Best Regards...

Answer (score 0):

> :\C:Windows\system32\SqlManagerUi.dll'

the path is incorrect :

where are the  `:\` from at the beginning ?